# Why different appearance even if same viewport, projection matrix and model view matrix?

Tags: opengl

Here is my scenario - I am using fixed function pipeline

I am drawing a circle in my `Draw` function. In this function before drawing the circle using `GLDrawCircle`, i am setting the `viewport`, `projection` matrix and `modelview` matrix. The `modelview` matrix is an identity matrix. When i exit the `Draw` function i reset the `viewport` & pop the `projection` and `modelview` matrix.

Also, for some bug in the inhouse render engine, i have to clear the `modelview` matrix stack (there is an overflow while drawing other staffs). So in the draw function, i clear the stack except keep one matrix in the stack.

Now, before calling this draw function, sometimes i need to do picking. For that i am doing following -

1. Enable a flag
2. Set the select buffer
3. Set `GL_SELECT` as render mode
4. Call `Draw` function for picking
5. set `GL_RENDER` as render mode & Disable the flag
6. Call `Draw` function for drawing

Problem -

If i do the picking then the circle appear differently. It seems like the camera has gone backwards and the circle appear small.

But i have debugged and checked that - the `modelview` matrix is always an identity matrix (both while picking and drawing), the `viewport` is always same and the `projection` matrix is always same as well. I have used following method to get the matrices and viewport -

```
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, ptr)
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, ptr)
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, ptr)
```

Can anyone please give me some idea what could be happening here? As of my understanding, if the `viewport`, `projection` matrix and `modelview` matrix is same then an object should always appear same.

Here is the full code - The `Draw` function without parameter is called by the engine.

```
typedef struct tagGLInitDrawCircle
{
public:
    CVKCompass* m_pClass;
    LONG        m_id;
    BOOL        m_bRes;
    tagGLInitDrawCircle(MyClass* cclas, LONG id) : m_id(id), m_pClass(cclas)
    {
        if(m_pClass)
            m_bRes = m_pClass->DrawCircleInit(id);
        else
            m_bRes = FALSE;
    }
    ~tagGLInitDrawCircle()
    {
        if(m_pClass && m_bRes)
            m_pClass->DrawCircleTerm(m_id);
    }

}   GLInitDrawCircle;


static double g_cosh[100];
static double g_sinh[100];
static GuBoolean g_bCosSinInit = FALSE;

static void GLDrawCircle(float r, float width, GuBoolean bFill)
{
    if(bFill == FALSE)
    {
        glLineWidth(width/2);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        for(int i=0 ; i<100 ; i++)
        {
            glVertex2f(r*g_cosh[i], r*g_sinh[i]);
        }
        glVertex2f(r*g_cosh[0], r*g_sinh[0]);
        glEnd();
        glLineWidth(width);
    }
    else
    {
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        for(int i=0 ; i<100 ; i++)
        {
            glVertex2f(r*g_cosh[i], r*g_sinh[i]);
        }
        glEnd();
    }
}







void MyClass::Draw()
{

    GLuint selectBuf[128];

    if (m_bSelectMode == TRUE)
    {
        memset(selectBuf, 0, 128 * sizeof(GLuint));

        glSelectBuffer(128, selectBuf);
        glRenderMode(GL_SELECT);

        glInitNames();
        glPushName(0);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        this->Draw(0);
        m_bSelectMode = FALSE;
        hits = glRenderMode(GL_RENDER);
    }

    this->Draw(1);
}

void MyClass::Draw(int type)
{
    GLint depth;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH, &depth);
    for (int i = 0; i < depth - 1; i++)
        glPopMatrix();

    GLUquadricObj* quadObj = (GLUquadricObj*)m_quadObj;
    GLUquadricObj* quadSphere = (GLUquadricObj*)m_quadSphere;


    if(g_bCosSinInit == FALSE)
    {
        g_bCosSinInit = TRUE;
        float pi_step = PI/50.f;
        for(int i=0 ; i<100 ; i++)
        {
            g_cosh[i] = cos(pi_step*i);
            g_sinh[i] = sin(pi_step*i);
        }
    }
    if(quadObj == NULL)
    {

        quadObj = gluNewQuadric();


        m_quadObj = (void*)quadObj;
    }
    if(quadSphere == NULL)
    {
        // Need to create a new quadratic object for the sphere
        quadSphere = gluNewQuadric();
        m_quadSphere = (void*)quadSphere;
    }

    GLInitDrawCircle initCircle(this, id, bResult);


    if(quadObj != NULL)
    {
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glPushMatrix();
        glLoadIdentity();


        DrawCircle();

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glPopMatrix();

    }
}

void MyClass::DrawCircle(void)
{    
    glColor4ub(1, 1, 1, 1);

    if (m_bSelectMode )
    {
        glLoadName(10);
        GLDrawCircle(30, 1, FALSE);
    }
    else
    {
        GLDrawCircle(30, 1, FALSE);
    }


}


BOOL MyClass::DrawCircleInit(LONG id)
{

    int width = 1351; 
    int height = 612;

    float scene_width = width / 10.0;
    float scene_height = height / 10.0;

    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, &m_viewport[0]);

    glViewport(5, 5, (GLsizei)scene_width, (GLsizei)scene_width);


    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();


    float ortho[6];

    ortho[0] = -scene_width;
    ortho[1] = scene_width  + offset_triad;
    ortho[2] = -scene_width - offset_height;
    ortho[3] = scene_width + offset_height;
    ortho[4] = -scene_width * 10;
    ortho[5] = scene_width * 10;
    glOrtho(ortho[0], ortho[1], ortho[2], ortho[3],
            ortho[4], ortho[5]);


    return TRUE;
}


BOOL MyClass::DrawCircleTerm(LONG id)
{

    glViewport(m_viewport[0], m_viewport[1], m_viewport[2], m_viewport[3]);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that produces the problem. What is `GLCircle`? How does it draw? A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is really required for that question.

Comment: @BDL The full code has been added. The `GLDrawCircle` function just calculates the vertices for a circle.

Answer (score 0):

This

> ```
>    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
>    this->Draw(0);
> ```

will just lead to

> ```
> glGetIntegerv(GL_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH, &depth);
> for (int i = 0; i < depth - 1; i++)
>     glPopMatrix();
> ```

so when you do your picking, you do not "clear" (seriously: fix your renderer) your modelview matrix stack, but the projection matrix stack (and most likely even underflow it).